# Split alphanumeric string between leading digits and trailing letters

Tags: php, regex, split, text-parsing, alphanumeric

I have a string like:

```
$Order_num = "0982asdlkj";
```

How can I split that into the 2 variables, with the number as one element and then another variable with the letter element?

The number element can be any length from 1 to 4 say and the letter element fills the rest to make every order_num 10 characters long in total.

I have found the php `explode` function...but don't know how to make it in my case because the number of numbers is between 1 and 4 and the letters are random after that, so no way to split at a particular letter.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) using [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "0982asdlkj"));
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0982
    [1] => asdlkj
)
```

This only works if the letter part really only contains letters and no digits.

**Update:**

Just to clarify what is going on here:

The regular expressions looks at every position and if a digit is before that position (`(?<=\d)`) *and* a letter after it (`(?=[a-z])`), then it matches and the string gets split at this position. The whole thing is case-insensitive (`i`).

Comment: What's the advantage of using split over match?

Comment: You need to escape the \ in \d.

Comment: @marcog: Good question... I was just focused on *splitting* the string ;) I'm not sure whether there is any advantage.

Comment: @marcog: No I don't, it works fine for me, even in double quotes, but to be sure, I will put it in single quotes.

Comment: @marcog: I think either way is fine, as Felix says it depends on your own way of thinking :)

Comment: @marcog that's the way stackoverflow works. They actually do answer the question without understanding it. They  even barely read it. You know, the fastest answer will more likely be accepted.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: There is not always *the only true answer* to a problem. People think in different ways. And knowing different ways to solve a problem is even better!

Comment: sure. but this noob will use your code as a magic chant, without slightest understanding. While straight preg_match would be way more readable and one can start learning regexp from this

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: And why can't someone learn regular expressions from lookarounds? Is it too advanced? Should we only give "simple" solutions? Btw. I'm the only one who actually linked to regex documentation so don't tell me that.

Comment: @Felix If he's struggling to split a string like he is, then yes simpler is better.

Comment: Yes, it's too advanced. Your solution is okay, I just hate it's being accepted and the way you took it - literally. Literal answers often do more harm than help.

Comment: @marcog: Of course simple solutions should be preferred. But what is simple? Is this code complicated? IMHO no! Is the expression complicated? Depends. It does not use quantifiers, it just matches one position and two characters. But why don't make use it if it is there (lookaround)?

Comment: @Felix `#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i` vs `/(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)/`: go back to your first week of exploring regular expressions, which do you think you'd understand first?

Comment: @marcog: Without any explanation probably none of these.

Comment: @Felix emphasis on first, i.e. you're learning regular expressions.

Comment: The discussion is over anyway. All I wanted is to show *one* way of doing it. It is not my fault that the OP accepted the answer. If some of you guys want to have *the-only-one-and-true-solution* then go and live in a *Brave new World*. Don't forget that the answers are not only for the person who asks but also for those who come after...

Comment: Hello, I am the OP.  I liked this answer because it was simple and solved my problem.  and because it SOLVED my problem, I know more about regex now, rather than reading pages and pages of waffle without learning a thing as is usual on SO.  Thanks to FK, and col. get off the high horse.  Good day to you all Gentlemen.

Comment: @David19801 good. What would be the pattern if you have to get 2 numbers out of string '1234werg3456'?

Comment: You'd do it once on the raw code, then flip the regex and do it again on array[1].

Comment: exactly what I needed 6 years after you posted your answer!

Answer (score 7):

Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with a regular expression of `(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)`. If you want to limit the number of digits to 1-4 and letters to 6-9, change it to `(\d+{1,4})([a-zA-Z]{6,9})`.

```
preg_match("/(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)/", "0982asdlkj", $matches);
print("Integer component: " . $matches[1] . "\n");
print("Letter component: " . $matches[2] . "\n");
```

Outputs:

```
Integer component: 0982
Letter component: asdlkj
```

http://ideone.com/SKtKs

Comment: `$matches = array();` is not really needed. `preg_match` will ensure that the array will alway exist, even when there is no match.

Comment: Also you need not escape \ in \\d+. \d+ is enough.

Comment: @codaddict: But it is good coding style and easier to understand for the less proficient PHP programmer IMO.

Comment: @codaddict Didn't know about the `array()`, but I don't like not escaping.

Comment: Or use this even simpler expression: /(\d+)(.*)/

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it using `preg_split` by splitting your input at the point which between the digits and the letters:

```
list($num,$alpha) = preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z]+)/i',$Order_num);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex for that.

```
preg_match('/(\d{1,4})([a-z]+)/i', $str, $matches);
array_shift($matches);
list($num, $alpha) = $matches;
```

Comment: I won't use strict limit on the number but beside that it's most sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<?php
$Order_num = "0982asdlkj";
$split=split("[0-9]",$Order_num);
$alpha=$split[(sizeof($split))-1];
$number=explode($alpha, $Order_num);
echo "Alpha -".$alpha."<br>";
echo "Number-".$number[0];
?>
```

with regards

**wazzy**

Comment: Upgrade your PHP from the ancient version to something modern and run it again

Comment: @Wazzy: Because people are crazy and downvote answers they *don't like*. To be fair, your solution is not very elegant, but it gives the right solution. I would not upvote it, but I would not downvote either. +1 from my to compensate.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Works fine with PHP 5.3.3

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: So `split` is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and can be replaced by `preg_split`... it still with `split` or `preg_split` it works. I'm against downvoting without explanation and *Upgrade your PHP from the ancient version to something modern and run it again* is not an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred approach would be `sscanf()` because it is concise, doesn't need regex, offers the ability to cast the numeric segment as integer type, and doesn't generate needless fullstring matches like `preg_match()`.  `%s` does rely, though, on the fact that there will be no whitespaces in the letters segment of the string.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jYgF1)

```
$Order_num = "0982asdlkj";
var_export (
    sscanf($Order_num, '%d%s')
);
```

This can also be set up to declare individual variables.

```
sscanf($Order_num, '%d%s', $numbers, $letters)
```

---

If wanting to use a `preg_` function, `preg_split()` is most appropriate, but I wouldn't use expensive lookarounds.  Match the digits, then forget them (with `\K`).  This will split the string without consuming any characters. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/AJgbj)

```
var_export (
    preg_split('/\d+\K/', $Order_num)
);
```

To assign variables, use "symmetric array destructuring".

```
[$numbers, $letters] = preg_split('/\d+\K/', $Order_num);
```

---

Beyond these single function approaches, there will be MANY two function approaches like:

```
$numbers = rtrim($Order_num, 'a..z');
$letters = ltrim($Order_num, '0..9');
```

But I wouldn't use them in a professional script because they lack elegance.