# Directory list into associative array

Tags: php, regex, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP split string into integer element and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string)

I have a directory with these files

```
FILEA10.TXT
FILEB20.TXT
FILEC5.TXT
```

I need to read the list into array:

```
filea => 10
fileb => 20
filec => 5
```

What is the fastest way or function to do this?

Comment: I just think I need to use some regex, but I'm new to it. No, I'm not asking for a complete code, only of which function in php. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: @iceberg you will need opendir(), readdir(), and ManseUK's linked question

Comment: @Iceberg check out http://codepad.org/1FaT4tJN

Comment: ManseUK gave me a good kick :) @lawrence thank for the code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
foreach (glob('*.TXT') as $file) {
   list($name,$num) = preg_split('/\.|(?<=\D)(?=\d+)/', $file);
   $arr[$name] = $num;
}
```