# Split variable using php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am grabbing the name attribute using `jquery` and passing it to my Controller via `ajax` call.

**VIEW**

```
<?php 
    $data = array(
    'name' => $id.$country,
    'class' => 'send',
    'content' => 'Send'
    );
   echo form_button($data);
   ?>
```

**JS**

```
var abc = $(self).attr("name");
```

I would like to know if there is any codeigniter php function which can help me to separate id from country and pass them to my model.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$abc = $this->input->post('abc');

$id = first part of abc variable
$country = second part of abc variable
```

Comment: Concatenating 2 entries is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: pass them seperately or use a concat string/char which id and country **must not** contain for any condition. i would send them seperately.

Comment: Has the `$id` every time a fixed length?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string

Comment: @EducateYourself Contains your id only numbers?

Comment: id contains only integer numbers. Can I split it in JS file and pass splitted variables to my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:**

As `@Jonast92` clarified in the comments this answer doesn't solve the solution, and i agree after re-looking at the question since the values do not actually contain a dot and are not in the form of `1.usa` but rather `1usa`.

*Note: I'll leave the initial answer below for reference but this would only work if the characters were separated by a (`.`) character and not concatenated directly.*

---

### Semi-Invalid Answer:

**IF** the string was concatenated using a `.` as a separator as in:
    'name' => $id . "." . $country,

You could `explode` that concatenated string into an array using:

```
$abc = explode(".",$abc);
```

Then the id will be stored at index 0  and country at index 1:

```
$id = $abc[0];
$country = $abc[1];
```

Just make sure that values do not contain any dot (`.`) characters as that would produce unwanted results.

**Note:** You can even limit the number of array elements using:

```
$abc = explode(".",$abc,2);
```

which will allow countries to still contain a dot without them breaking up further into an array.

**Optimal Solution** though would be to split those two values and pass them as seperate parameters before even posting them to the `php` page and only concatenate them if necessary for your application elsewhere.

Comment: `$abc` does not contain `.` (far as we know, so we can't explode by it), he simply concatenated the variables `$id` and `$country` with the concatenation keyword `.` in PHP, which has nothing to do with `.` being a part of the string.

Comment: Nice catch there @Jonast92 didn't notice at first read, thanks.

Comment: @Kypros it can be a valid answer if you add a line `'name' => $id.".".$country,` **though i would not recommend concat as mentioned in my previous comment**

Comment: @karan thakkar, why is it a bad idea to concat the variables?

Comment: @EducateYourself It's iffy and risky. It relies on data and implementation never to change, which you can't always guarantee.

Comment: @EducateYourself Because it would make your life (and others probably) easier (no need to concat and then split again), each parameter could have it's own type (`integer`,`string` in your case) and you could use/validate them separately, ie `isset($_POST['country']){ }`

Comment: what if I split the variable in JS file and pass splitted variables to controller?

Comment: Same thing, what if i have `javascript` disabled? Your code logic will most probably break. Any particular reason you need to concatenate them? I can't seem to find any real benefits of doing that apart from maybe presentation in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$str = $this->input->post('abc');
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

EXAMPLE:

```
$str = '1654usa';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

To echo out the number use: `echo $matches[0][0];`

This will return 1654, because the regular expression searches the string for numbers, and will "pull out" all the numbers.

Comment: And can you elaborate to OP what it's suppose to do and how?

Comment: @Jonast92 check updated answer, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if the id only contains numbers!

```
<?php 

    $str = '234534534Virgin Islands (U.S.)';
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    $id = $matches[0][0];
    preg_match_all('/((?!\d+).)*$/', $str, $matches);
    $country = $matches[0][0];

    echo $id . "<br />" . $country;

?>
```

Output:

```
234534534
Virgin Islands (U.S.)
```

Comment: it would fail if i live in `Guinea-Bissau` **or** `Falkland Islands (Malvinas)` **or** `Virgin Islands (U.S.)` etc  **for eg**

Comment: @karanthakkar thanks for notice my! i fixed it! all you examples work now!

Comment: not sure about the down voter but nice update ! update output too :P it can't be `Switzerland` now. jk, cheers ;)

Comment: i didnt said it can't work with Switzerland, i just said there **was** contrast in your code (Virgin Islands (U.S.)) and op (Switzerland). which you corrected  afterwords ;)

Comment: @karanthakkar yep stupid mistake ;) you can upvote the answer if you think it's correct, so that OP see's the answer faster!

Comment: already done but i would prefer not to concat as you can see in all my comments throughout the question.