# Decrement operator for strings bug in PHP?

Tags: php, string, increment, decrement

There is an inconsistency in increment/decrement operator function regarding strings in -at least- my version of PHP. Here is what I mean:

```
php > echo phpversion();
7.4.11
php > $test = 'abc12';
php > // increment works as expected
php > echo(++$test);
abc13
php > echo(++$test);
abc14
php > echo(++$test);
abc15
php > // but decrement fails
php > echo(--$test);
abc15
php > echo(--$test);
abc15
php > echo(--$test);
abc15
```

Is this an expected behavior? Should I file a bug report or something? Do you know of a workaround?

edit: filed [bug#80212](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80212)

Comment: Why should you increment or decrement strings?

Comment: Increment/decrement operator only are supposed to work on types that have a single numerical value. It surprises me more that in the increment works on `'abc12'`. The question of Markus is justified. Why would you expect to be able to increment/decrement a non-numerical value this way?

Comment: Per the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):  "The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and strings. Arrays, objects, booleans and resources are not affected. Decrementing NULL values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1." My actual use case is for namespace versioning..

Comment: I understand that you take the "string" type in the broadest sense, but that's not justified. How would you increment a string like "Wonderful"? You can't, because it's not numeric in any way. So we can probably agree that not all strings will work?

Comment: You need to split your names into two parts. What you can use is something this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537994/php-split-string-into-integer-element-and-string

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware but "Wonderfum" is a valid increment of "Wonderful". And it actually works. I really think this is a bug or in the very least, it should be made clear in the manual.

Comment: Haha, well, there you go. Yes, I agree the manual isn't all that clear.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Alphanumeric sequences are a thing. Think of car plates or spreadsheet columns.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Then there must be a unique rule to have numbers at beginning or end of the string. Better separate them and do manually.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Well, a tool doesn't need to cover every use case ever to deserve existing 

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I would not like to compare a tool with a language construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally went with:

```
function decrement($str) {
  $matches = preg_split('/(\d+)\z/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  @--$matches[1];
  return implode($matches);
}
```

Wouldn't call it *elegant* but I'd call it *functional*.

Answer (score 2):

That's the [documented behaviour](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) (emphasis mine):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that **character variables can be incremented but not decremented** and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Comment: As per the current status of my [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80212), 'this important note should be more prominent'. And it still is bafflingly inconsistent.