# add INT with STRING in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to add the int with strings in PHP but I could get a helpful answer on StackOverflow and other website communities.

I want the code separate the ALPHABETS and NUMBER and then add the value in NUMBER and again JOIN the ALPHABETS AND ADDED NUMBER together.

How I achieve this, Please help.

Example:

```
$mynumber  = 'SBI0001';
$addValue = '1';
```

It will be `'SBI0002'` in PHP.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538057/7993505

Comment: Search for each part separately. Eg _"php extract prefixed number"_ and _"php format number with leading zeros"_

Comment: @Richard it showing only number 1 but it should be `001`
`preg_match("/(\\d+)([0-9]+)/", "MFG001", $matches);
$string = $matches[1];
$number = $matches[2];
echo $number;`

Comment: @ShubhamNagar You can not add an int (`1`) to an string (`001`): Workflow: 1) find your number | 2) count the zeros e.g.: `preg_match_all('/(0*)1/', $original_input, $output_array);` | 3) rebuild your string = `string`+`zeros`*x+`newValue`