# String to array Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to convert seats to an array in the controller.

this is how the seats data is sent to the controller
seats
:
"B7D7G10"

i want to convert it to look something like this "B7 , D7 , G10" and I want to match the seats data with my seats table so i can change the seats values in the seats table

This is my `jQuery` function.

```
$("#purchase").on("click",function() {
    var data = {
        seats: $(".seats-selected").text(),
        seats_id: $(".seats-selected").data('sid'),
        theatre_id: $("#theatres").data('tid'),
        movie_id: $(".movie_id").val(),
        movie: $("#m-title").text(),
        theatre: $("#theatres").text(),
        date: $("#date").text(),
        time: $("#time").val(),
        total_price: $("#total-p").text(),
    };
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send-email",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Your Theatre" + data.theatre + "\n" + data.seats_id + "\n" + data.date + "\n" + data.time + "\n" + data.total_price + "\n" );
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller:

```
    $seats = $request->seats;
    $theatre_id = $request->theatre_id;
    $date = $request->date;
    $time = $request->time;
    $movie_id = $request->movie_id;
    $total_price =  $request->total_price;    
    $bookings = bookings::where('theatre_id', $theatre_id)
                    ->where('date', $date)
                    ->where('time', $time)
                    ->where('movie_id', $movie_id)
                    ->get();

    $reserved_seats = $bookings->pluck('seat_number')->toArray();

    $seat = seats::where('seat_number', $request->seats_id)
                ->where('theatre_id', $theatre_id)
                ->where('movie_id', $movie_id)
                ->first();

    if ($seat && !in_array($seat->id, $reserved_seats)) {
        $seat->available = 0;
        $seat->save();

        // add the booking to the bookings table
        $booking = new bookings;
        $booking->theatre_id = $theatre_id;
        $booking->movie_id = $movie_id;
        $booking->seat_number = explode(',',$seats);
        $booking->date = $date;
        $booking->time = $time;
        $booking->total_price = $total_price;
        $booking->user_id = auth()->id();
        $booking->save();
```

I tried every method `implode`, `explode`, `array_map`, everything it won't work if i just leave it be it will only change the value of the first seat. What I wanna do is save the values in bookings table (seat_number column) e.g like this: `A1, B9, G10` and match the seats the AJAX request is sending to the controller from the seats table and change its available value to 0.

Comment: can you log what your request looks like or even the json data you are posting through ajax?

Comment: Might need more details here. You say *"it will only change the value of the first seat"*, but you're only querying for a single Seat anyway... Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75316837/edit) with more details. Also, your deadline is not relevant to the question, please don't add it to your title 

Comment: this is my json data date
: 
February 01 Wednesday"
movie
: 
"Hacksaw Ridge"
movie_id
: 
"78"
seats
: 
"B7D7G10"
seats_id
: 
25
theatre
: 
The Silver Screen "
theatre_id
: 
2
time
: 
"10:00 PM"
total_price
: 
"PKR.3000"

Comment: yeah thats the question how do i query for every seat my seats data looks something like this
seats
: 
"B7D7G10" 
these are 3 different seats "B7 D7 G10"

Comment: `explode(',', $seats);` is not going to work on `"B7D7G10"`; there's no `,` separating them. If you sent `"B7,D7,G10"`, then that `explode()` call would convert it to an array. But still, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your data, or what your `bookings` table looks like, etc., so we won't be able to help much beyond pointing out syntax issues, sorry

Comment: If you send multiple Seat IDs as an array, then you'd be able to do `seats::whereIn('id', $seatIdsAsAnArray)->get()` to get multiple Seats, but again, still not sure how you'd get that in your `bookings` table, since that data would not be normalized. (Sidenote, Model names should be `PascalCase` and singular, so `Seat`, `Booking`, etc, not `seats`, `bookings`)

Comment: yeah i tried that id method too but same problem

Comment: how do i separate them with , while sending them to the controller

Comment: As expected, `whereIn()` needs an array, but you've only got Strings. You're gonna have to have a look at your front-end. Right now you're just doing `seats: $(".seats-selected").text()`, which will send `A1B2C3` (or similar), since that's what `.text()` returns. You have to change that, _somehow_... I can't see your front-end code, so I have no idea _how_ you need to change that, but you do. Do some searching on how to either manipulate strings in JS, or how to send an Array via AJAX (which is possible), and then you won't need to do `explode()` on the back-end at all.

Comment: this is what my front end looks like https://paste.pics/60d5919529a74b0470936e2ea6319abe
im getting the selected seats text the 2 little orange boxes with seats number

Answer (score 1):

If you need to separate the string with no delimiting characters, then split on the zero-width space after each sequence of numbers.

`\K` forgets the previously matched characters so that they are not lost in the splitting process.  `preg_split()`'s advantage over `preg_match_all()` is that `preg_split()` only creates a flat array whereas `preg_match_all()` creates a 2d array -- of which only its first row is used.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Lq8Mf))

```
$seats = "B7G12D9";

var_export (
    preg_split('/\d+\K/', $seats, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'B7',
  1 => 'G12',
  2 => 'D9',
)
```

[Here's the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73184403/2943403) of the same pattern on a different string for a different effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to split up a string like `B7D9H12` with a regular expression.

In PHP you'd have

```
<?php

$seats = "B7G12D9";
$pat = "/([A-Z]\d+)/";  // Search for A to Z followed by one or more digits and capture
preg_match_all($pat, $seats, $matches);
$seatArray = $matches[0];         // Extract the captured data from the $matches array
var_dump($seatArray);
```

Giving an array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "B7"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "G12"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "D9"
}
```

You can do something similar in Javascript if you prefer.

See https://3v4l.org/bfZka

Comment: The capture group in the pattern is not used or necessary.